# How to build an Eclipse plugin with maven?

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin

How do you build an Eclipse plugin with Maven?  What dependencies or plugins do I need?  I am looking to develop for Eclipse 3.7.

Comment: Perhaps dated, but http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Eclipse-and-Maven2/index.html may give some tips

Comment: You should have a look to the Tycho project which is the way to go for building Eclipse plug-ins with Maven: http://www.eclipse.org/tycho/

Answer (score 4):

You can use Maven 3.3 (at least) and Maven Tycho 0.24.0. Add this to your project's *.mvn/extensions.xml*:

```
<extensions>
  <extension>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>tycho-pomless</artifactId>
    <version>0.26.0</version>
  </extension>
</extensions>
```

Then you must define your pom.xml according to the structure of your project.
I recommend this article: [Eclipse Tycho for building Eclipse Plug-ins, OSGi bundles and RCP applications - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html)

You can follow the example on this page to have a general idea of using maven plugin Tycho.

Comment: I have met the same problem as the asker. The solution proposed in the article works perfectly.

Comment: The updated answer at least provides a bit more context than the original