# Continue development of Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-pde

There is an Eclipse Plugin managed by Maven containing this configuration:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>wonttellya</groupId>
        <artifactId>wonttellya</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
        <dependencies>
            ...
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                <configuration>
                    <pde>true</pde>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

In console I run

```
C:\Users\user\git\wonttellya\mvn 
         eclipse:eclipse -Declipse.workspace=C:\Users\user\workspace2
...
Using Eclipse Workspace: C:\Users\user\workspace2    
...
BUILD SUCCESS
```

If I open Eclipse in the workspace there is no project.

Comment: The intention of the [maven-eclipse-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/) is to create/change/upgrade the eclipse configuration from command line etc. It is usually not needed in the pom to be configured.

Comment: @khmarbaise https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/pde.html told me to configure it

Comment: Ah ok...wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you have to understand that the purpose of the [`maven-eclipse-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/index.html) is, quoting its documentation:

> to generate Eclipse IDE files (*.classpath, *.project, *.wtpmodules and the .settings folder) for use with a project.

Its goal is not to create an entire project but the building Eclipse blocks from an *existing* project.

This is also true for PDE support. [Quoting its documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/pde.html):

> Note that the scope of the `maven-eclipse-plugin` is to synchronise the Eclipse `.project` and `.classpath` files with the configuration found in the pom file. Once you have finished configuring the Eclipse plugin as below, and once you have run the `eclipse:eclipse` goal, you will be in a position to build your plugin code with the Eclipse IDE, or the Eclipse headless PDE build. The Eclipse headless PDE build can be triggered from within Maven using the `pde-maven-plugin`.

As such, the configuration you have simply enables the creation of correct `.project` and `.classpath` files for an existing project, nothing more. Once this configuration has been made and `eclipse:eclipse` goal was run, you will need to follow these steps:

- Open Eclipse and import the existing project, by going to "File > Import... > Existing Projects into Workspace".
- Right-click the new project and select "Configure > Convert to Plugins Projects...". Confirm this choice.

You will then be able to build your Eclipse plugin directly in the IDE.

Note that I do not recommend using this solution and I would suggest you use Tycho instead, this might be an improvement you could make to this plugin (refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6830399/1743880)).

Comment: Please note that the Maven Eclipse Plugin is deprecated in favor of m2e and will be removed from the ASF.

Comment: @Michael-O Yes, m2e should definitely be prefered over Maven Eclipse Plugin. Official JIRA about the retirement of this plugin: [MECLIPSE-763](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MECLIPSE-763).

Comment: I did that but the project is not marked as "Eclipse Plugin".

Comment: @PeterRader What do you mean? What did you do?

Comment: I "just open eclipse and import the existing project, by going ...". The project is imported but its not a PDE-Project. What sense does the `<pde>` in the `pom.xml` make?

Comment: @PeterRader See my edit, forgot to add that you need to convert it to a Plugins project.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you   have update your project before you run the maven install 
Try to click on your project with the right mouse button and go to maven-->update project

For  a different clause 
You can use export and import with archive (.zip) that you can manage Plugin and simply transfert your project in different workspaces

Comment: The task of `eclipse:eclipse` is :**Generates the following eclipse configuration files:...**. If the project already visible in the workspace, the configuration-files already exists and i do not need to call `eclipse:eclipse`.